# How to uninstall Netbeans 6.9 on Windows 7?

Tags: uninstallation, netbeans-6.9

I try to uninstall the Netbeans IDE. for some reason it refuses to uninstall.

When I run the uninstaller from the control panel, I get a message saying:

> the installer lock file exists at c:\users\user.nbi.nbilock"

When I remove the file I get a message saying:

> the specified target component -nb- base/6.9.0.0.0 was not found in the registry. the installer can continue as if the targer component was not specified.
>   click Yes to continue, No to exit the installer"

When I click *Yes* it finishes very quickly and nothing really gets uninstalled.

In general when I try to run NetBeans it says:

> cannot locate Java installation in specified jdkhome
>   c:\program files (x86)\ java jdk1.6.0_20
>   do you want to try to use default version?"

Once again yes or no. Yes will open the IDE normally.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same thing happen to me.  I put a co-workers image on my PC (same hardware) that contained a baseline suite of applications, including Netbeans.  I actually happened to have Netbeans 6.9 and Windows 7 too, but that has nothing to do with it.

I deleted my co-workers profile, and that is why I got the error you speak of.  Some needed files are contained in `C:\Users\JohnB\`.  Here are the folders that Netbeans installs in your user profile folder:

[image]

I simply had my co-worker copy and send them to me, I put them in the profile they got deleted from, then the **uninstall** process worked perfectly.

Here's the post that pointed me in the right direction:

- [cannot uninstall Netbeans 6.7 Beta](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic14075.html)

Here's a related post that explains how to clean up after incomplete installations, but I did not have these rogue registry entries on my PC:

- [Cleaning Up After Incomplete Installations](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/65/install.html#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Netbeans 7.01 IDE OK but then zf tool kept throwing exception. I found a .zf file in my profile and sure enough it was looking for a netbeans file. I removed the statement and Voila! zf tool worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I deleted the .nbi file. Then the uninstall was not working at all. Finally I manually delete the folders of netbeans. I know this is wrong... I think it got corrupted somehow and was not possible to uninstall.