# Why does NetBeans not install updates?

Tags: netbeans, plugins, installation

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 (build 201408251540; 64 bit) on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

When I check for updates via *Help* > *Check for Updates* I see the following dialog:

[image: NetBeans IDE Installer dialog showing updates to install]

When I then click *Next >* it says that it downloads them in the status bar and after a moment I get a balloon tooltip saying that I need to restart the IDE to complete the installation. So far, so good.

Though after restarting I get the same updates offered again. So it obviously failed to install them.

I already tried the following:

1. Started NetBeans as administrator
2. Set full access rights to users on the NetBeans installation folder
3. Started netbeans.exe instead of netbeans64.exe

Why are the updates failing? Is there some protocol I can enable to see what is going on?

Comment: Something else to try would be clearing out the cache and/or user configuration directories. That seems to solve a lot of weird problems for me. Or check the messages.log file for clues.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Clearing the cache (under `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0`) did not help. I guess the user configuration files are located in `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0`, right? The messages.log file (under `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\var\log\`) includes some warnings, though no errors.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to uninstall NetBeans and getting the message

> The specified target component - nb-base/8.0.0.0.xxx was not found in the registry. The installer can continue as if the target component was not specified.

(see [How to uninstall Netbeans 6.9 on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3954199/432681)) I downloaded the latest version of NetBeans from netbeans.org and reinstalled NetBeans 8.0.2 over my previous installation.

When I now check for updates the NetBeans IDE Installer tells me that my IDE is up to date. So it looks like my problem is solved.